# If condition in a for loop to ensure a string is found in an array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, conditional-statements

Using an array of 3 words which is randomly generated from another function, I'm trying to get a function to check whether a certain i word in a loop, which is given from the src of an image file, is found in the array generated from that other function, and in case it isn't - that other function would run again until the word would be included in the array.

```
var gFlavors = ['vanilla', 'chocolate', 'strawberry', 'lemon', 'peanutbutter']

function getFlavor(flavor) {
    var options = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= gFlavors.length; i++) {
    // I have a folder of images, with the images named "1-vanilla.gif", "2-chocolate.gif" and so on. Using the loop, I am getting those images and setting a class and data for each
    flavor = new Image(150, 150);
    flavor.src = 'img/' + i + '-' + gFlavors[i - 1] + '.gif';
    flavor.setAttribute('class', 'flavor');
    flavor.setAttribute('data-flavor', gFlavors[i - 1]);
    var elFlavorsDiv.appendChild(flavor);

    // Slicing solely the flavor word found in each image filename
    var flavorImgSrc = flavor.attributes.src.nodeValue;
    var flavorImgSrcDash = flavorImgSrc.indexOf('-');
    var flavorStr = flavorImgSrc.slice(flavorImgSrcDash + 1, flavorImgSrc.length - 4);
    options = generateOptions();

    // The problematic line which doesn't do what I want it to: To check whether an i flavor is included in the generated random array (and if it isn't - re-generate the random array until the flavor is included) - For example: The generated random array is ['strawberry', 'peanutbutter', 'chocolate'] - if i is currently one of the 3 flavors found in the array, keep the array as it is, on the other hand if i is for example 'lemon' - re-run generateOptions() until the current i is found there - so I only get an array matching the current i
    if (!options[i].includes(flavorStr)) options = generateOptions();
}


// A function returning an array of 3 random flavors
function generateOptions() {
    var randomizedOptions = gFlavors;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        shuffle(randomizedOptions);
        randomizedOptions.splice(0, randomizedOptions.length-3)
    }
    return randomizedOptions;
}

// A shuffle function for arrays
function shuffle(array) {
    array.sort(() => (Math.random() - 0.5));
}
```

Example of expected result:
The generated random array is ['strawberry', 'peanutbutter', 'chocolate'] - If i is currently one of the 3 flavors found in the array, keep the array as it is, on the other hand if i is for example 'lemon' - re-run generateOptions() until the current i is found there - so I only get an array matching the current i.

As of now, I am receiving a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') at getFlavor

Comment: Please add a question. What is the issue and the expected result. Include a minimal, reproducible example for use to run so we can debug your code. In the question editor look for the `<>` icon to create a runnable snippet.

Comment: Hi @EmielZuurbier, updated, thank you

Comment: Your `for` loop runs over 5 strings, while your `options` array is only 3 strings long. So eventually, at the 4th iteration, there will be no string to select and `options[i]` will return undefined. That's the cause of the error.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I see. To fix this, do I better write another loop which would only run on 3 (for j = 0; j < options.length; j++)? Or another method?

Comment: A `while` loop might be a good solution for checking if your array contains any of the words in the array until there is one. Though, to be sure, what value will be `flavorStr` be? Is it `'vanilla'`,  `'chocolate'`, etc?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I attempted this with while (!options.includes(flagStr)) {
   options = generateOptions();
  // } but it went into an infinite loop. Indeed, flavorStr is the flavor word - the one which has to appear once in the array (and as long as the generated array hasn't included it - a new array will keep generating)

Comment: Your `generateOptions` function will only ever return the first three items of the `gFlavors` array. So `'lemon'` and `'peanutbutter'` will never be included, therefor your loop is infinite. Move the `shuffle(randomizedOptions);` before the `for` loop. This will shuffle the array first and **then** select the first three (which are now in random order)

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Just tried it. I receive the same Tyeperror when I try it with my if condition if (!options[i].includes(flagStr)) options = generateOptions() and on the other hand I go into an infinite loop when I try it with while (!options.includes(flagStr)) {
   options = generateOptions();
   }

Answer (score 0):

Your `generateOptions` function returns void.

So therefore `options` is undefined, meaning `options[i]` would throw.

Comment: Hi skara, what do you mean? My generateOptions function actually works and returns a proper array, just tested.

Comment: I don't see a return statement anywhere in there.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to include the return line in the actual stackoverflow post (while it actually was in the code itself). Fixed :) I assume EmilZuurbier in the comment above has pointed out the problem, but I'm having difficulties solving it.